# Get .net decimal.MinValue In JS

Tags: javascript, .net, decimal

```
decimal minValue = decimal.MinValue; //= -79228162514264337593543950335
```

I need the value of this .NET variable `decimal.MinValue` in my JavaScript.

Any idea?

Comment: JS knows nothing of .NET. So you'll need to tell it. --- Echo the value to HTML, and then use JS to grab it.

Comment: The ECMAScript [*Number.MIN_VALUE*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-number.min_value) is in the language specification. Also see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE).